# Not able to find /opt /var /tmp in lsblk RHEL 8.1

Tags: rhel, rhel8

Am Not able to find /opt /var /tmp in lsblk RHEL 8.1.Can you please help me.

```
[xxx@exxx ~]$ lsblk
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0   64G  0 disk
+-sda1              8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot/efi
+-sda2              8:2    0  500M  0 part /boot
+-sda3              8:3    0    2M  0 part
+-sda4              8:4    0   60G  0 part
+-rootvg-rootlv 253:5    0   60G  0 lvm  /
```

Answer (score 0):

`lsblk`

`lsblk` is used to ***display details about block devices and these block devices(Except ram disk) are basically those files that represent devices connected to the pc***. It queries `/sys` virtual file `system` and `udev db` to obtain information that it displays. And it basically displays output in a tree-like structure. This command comes pre-installed with the util-Linux package.

That is the reason you are unable to saw the directories `/opt`, `/var` and `/tmp`

`/opt` is for “the installation of add-on application software packages”.

`/var` is a standard subdirectory of the root directory in Linux and other Unix-like operating systems that contains files to which the system writes data during the course of its operation.

`/tmp` directory is a temporary landing place for files.